# Sql Azure Sync Dataset not supporting custom DataType of the tables while try to sync, is there any workaround for that?

Tags: sql, azure, ssis, dataset, synchronization

The On-premises Database have tables and those tables columns types are UDTs, for this reason created same UDTs and tables using these UDTs on the cloud.

But when trying to syncing them its shows error not supporting UDTs, So am I missing something or is there any workaround to do syncing with UDTs?

Here if SQL Azure allows to create UDTs & also allows to create tables using those datatypes, then why not allow to sync?

Comment: If the azure sync mechanism not at all allowing UDTs, then is it possible for creating SSIS package on top of on-premises database and sync through this SSIS package with azure database and this sync must be both way?

Answer (score 0):

FYI "SQL Azure" is called now "SQL Database" so if you find reference to Windows Azure "SQL Database" you can consider applied to your requirement as well.

SQL Database does not support user-defined data types, extended properties, Windows authentication, or the USE statement.

However the **November 2010 update to SQL Server 2008 R2 includes support for SQL Database**. The Generate Scripts Wizard now allows you to script for database version SQL Database so the scripts generated are directly compatible to be executed on SQL Database.  The scripts thus generated are compatible with SQL Database and can be compiled on SQL Database without any further modifications. So your UDDT or custom data types can my transferred to SQL Database through this migration script.

If your Database is pre-SQL Server 2008, you can use the "Schema Migration with pre-SQL Server 2008 R2" section from [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/994.develop-and-deploy-with-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for replay, but I don't want change the User Defined Datatype of on-premises db tables, that's why searching the solution for azure dataset sync with UDDT.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there is no workaround at this time. The Data Sync Service is largely based on Sync Framework and it doesn't support UDT as well. The Data Sync Service supports spatial data types in the latest release though.

Comment: Thanks June, If the azure sync mechanism not at all allowing UDTs, then is it possible for creating SSIS package on top of on-premises database and sync through this SSIS package with azure database and this sync must be both way?

OR

by writing code in c# is it possible?

Comment: I have a similar issue here. Can you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768341/using-sqldatarecord-inside-azure-worker-role